# VS2010 Professional Installation

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

When I tried to install VS2010 from the DVD drive, I get error **"Visual 2010 Professional Error right at beginning of Install - MSI returned error code 1612"**

The log file is copied to this [link](https://gist.github.com/murali0009/5159807)

What could be the reason?

As mentioned in the visual studio forums the vslogs.cab is present in the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5ofk2oyin1go8sy/YmMKjgs2cT).

Comment: Did you run the Prerequisites  check?

Comment: How will you check that?.. I have Windows 7 64-bit PC, which is already installed with VS2008.. Do i need to uninstall this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install VS2010 after installing the fix from this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall).